# how refresh div containing image without reloading page?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have project for my study I read x,y from touch pad and draw it as real time drawing with php, I create draw page that take x,y and draw it on an image, another page display this image (inside div)
it must be displayed many time in second I try to use ajax but it dose not work on the image unless I refresh the page manually
then I use this  
but this way is not acceptable by my supervisor!!!
please I need any helpful idea to refresh the div that contain the image from the code

Comment: what did you do to `try using ajax`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refresh the div while it contains the same image? Is that because the image itself changes (is rendered each time on request)? 
If so, you're browser cache is probably your problem. You can set the img src url to the base img url and add a parameter, like `yourimage.jpg?x`, where x is a value you change each time. That way, you'll byass the browser cache.

You don't need Ajax to load images. You can just set the img src or a div background-image to do that. The browser will automatically load it.

I doubt however if you can do this so many times a second.

Comment: thx for reply this is what exactly happened,, yeah the div contains the same image could u please explain me how to do add parameter?

Comment: btw I dose not use ajax, i call the following function onload:

function begin(){
document.getElementById("img").src = "image.png";
setTimeout('begin()', 1000);
}

Comment: If you do `document.getElementById('img').src = 'image.jpg?' + imageNum`, the value of the imageNum variable is added to the url. You can make imageNum a global variable with an initial value of 0, and increase its value every time before you update the src attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're going about it the wrong way. You should be using a `<canvas>` element and drawing directly inside the client browser, rather than round-tripping everything through the server.

However, if you insist on the round trip, then have your AJAX "send the touch data to the server" routine wait until the server's confirmed that it's processed the touch data and generated a new image, then simply reload the image in your client.

Comment: Agreed, although dynamic generation of SVG generally works better, especially on low-powered devices like iPads.  However, if he's targeting the Android devices, he's still SOL.

Comment: thank you,, I'm not insist to use such way I'm just a beginner in php :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refresh the div multiple times, u can use the basic js code...

**example for 1 refresh**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function timeMsg()
{
var t=setTimeout("alertMsg()",3000);
}
function alertMsg()
{
alert("Hello");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Display alert box in 3 seconds"
onclick="timeMsg()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**infinite loop::::**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var c=0;
var t;
var timer_is_on=0;

function timedCount()
{
document.getElementById('txt').value=c;
c=c+1;
t=setTimeout("timedCount()",1000);
}

function doTimer()
{
if (!timer_is_on)
  {
  timer_is_on=1;
  timedCount();
  }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Start count!" onclick="doTimer()">
<input type="text" id="txt" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```